# Debugging react native Apps

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I run into serious trouble debugging a `react native` app.

1. I installed the newest version of `xCode` as well as `expo`.
2. Start a `iOS Simulator` in `xCode`
3. Create a new App/Project with `expo` (the one with the navbar)
4. I send the project to the `iOS Simulator` which then opens the App.

When I click `Debug JS Remotely` GoogleChrome opens and with the `dev Tools` I can work just as I am used to. However, when I add an error into the code, i.e. deleting a `{`, and then save the file, the App reloads (Hot Reloading) and I get an error (in the Simulator). The error does **not** appear in the console of my GoogleChrome Browser.

1. Why is that?

Even worse, when I remove the error (here: adding the `{` where it belongs), and save the file, the App does not reload. I get errors like `__fbBatchedBridge` which are totally unrelated to the `{`-error. In order to get rid of these error I  have to create a new Project with `expo` (which contains the code without the `{`-error) and send this to the `iOS Simulator`. Only then, the error (i.e. `_fbBatchedBridge`) goes away.

2. Why do I have to create a new Project every time an error occurs. There is something very wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what kind of issue you are facing right now related to google chrome. But as you said the error `_fbBatchedBrdige` you don't need to create project again and again. You have to comment the code in `packager.sh` file.

Check below path in your project

> node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh

Check for below code in packager.sh

```
 if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then     
      echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"       
      exit 0;       
    fi
```

replace it with:

```
#    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then        
#      echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"      
#      exit 0;      
#    fi
```

Comment: Looks strange. Please comment the above lines in another file also from path node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh

Comment: thats where i found them. I do not have the folder `packager`.